# Unescape text in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an Automator workflow where text is passed from Combine Text Files into a Run Applescript action. I can get the text using `text of item 1 of input` but the text shows enclosed in quotation marks and the internal quotes are \escaped. How can I get the text "as is" without the escaping so I can run the imported code?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That is just how AppleScript represents a string with those characters.  If you do something like display it in a dialog or copy to the clipboard, you will not see escape characters.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! What if I want to run the text input as AppleScript code? And anticipating the next question—I am trying to import AppleScript code from a text file and run it.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you may need to escape the script text.  You might want to edit your question to include _exactly_ what you are trying to do, perhaps including a sample script you want to run.

Comment: @red_menace I have added a screenshot which shows what I am trying to do. Thanks for the sugestion!

Comment: The script in your screenshot isn’t running anything.  Note that since (hopefully) no-one can see your files, you need to explain things in detail.

Comment: Manually, I open the text file in Script Editor and click "Run". I am trying to automate that process of running files containing AppleScript code. I am not sure how to explain it more clearly...

Comment: The command you are looking for is `run script`, so in the **Run AppleScript** action the statement would be `return (run script (first item of input))`.  Note that `run script` will accept a script as text or a file.

Comment: That is working! THANK YOU @red_menace! :) If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Run AppleScript** action doesn’t alter or escape its input, but text may be shown that way depending on how you are viewing it (the different ways to view the result of an action, for example), since that is how characters such as double quotes or backslashes are typically represented in a string.

The [run script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW36) command can be used for running arbitrary script text, in which case you can do something like:

```
return (run script (first item of input))
```

Note that the `run script` command will also accept files directly, so in that case you wouldn’t really need the **Combine Text Files** action.